# Shell Function: Sequence of Pipelines as Argument

Tags: bash, array, function, arguments, parameter

I have a shell function (in .bashrc) which creates a temp file, executes the arguments (including all sequence of pipelines), redirects it to a temp file and then open it in VS Code.

I invoke the shell function as

```bsh
Temp "ls | nl"
```

In the follwoing code, I tried to make it work.
I break the entire string with IFS as a space, store it in an array. Now I want to execute the entire sequence of pipelines and redirect the final stdout to the temp file. How can I achieve this.? I know that for loop won't work here. But I want to print the entire array.

```bsh
Temp() {
    a="$(mktemp --suffix=.md "/tmp/$1-$(GetFilename "$2")-XXX")"
    IFS=' ' read -r -a Array <<< "$1"
    nArray=${#Array[@]} # Size of array
    for ((i=0; i<nArray; i=i+1)); do

    done
    #"${@}" > "$a"
    code -r "$a"
}
```

---

In the interactive terminal session the following works:

```bsh
cat <<EOF
$(ls | nl)
EOF
```

So, I tried Heredoc, instead of the for loop inside the function

```
cat > "$a" <<EOF
$($1)
EOF
```

But this puts quotes around `|` and thus fails.

The above would work, if we could remove the quotes somehow.

---

This also doesn't work

```bsh
cat > "$a" <<EOF
$(echo $1 | sed "s/'//g")
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function to execute a shell command given as an argument, you'll need to use `eval` on the string, e.g. this prints `FOO`:

```
eval_arg() {
    eval "$1"
}
eval_arg "echo foo |tr a-z A-Z"
```

Just expanding `"$1"` won't do, since shell grammar like pipes, quotes and redirections aren't processed after parameter expansions. Splitting the first argument to an array or to `$@` doesn't really change this.

---

So, `$(ls | nl)` has a verbatim pipe character, which is processed in the shell, but in `$($1)`, any special characters within the value of `$1` aren't processed (apart from word splitting and globs). There are no quotes in play here.

As for that last example, `$(echo $1 | sed "s/'//g")` splits the value of `$1` on whitespace (word splitting with the default `IFS`), then joins the words with spaces (`echo`), passes that as input to `sed` which removes any single quotes there.

Hence:

```
$ set -- "'foo  bar'"
$ $(echo $1 | sed "s/'//g")
foo bar
```

The outer quotes in the `set` command are processed by the shell, while the inner quotes are part of the value. Note that just `set -- 'foo bar'` would not result in `$1` containing any quotes, the only quotes here would be removed as part of the normal shell processing.